# Existing Pv to a new pod

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, volume, persistent-volumes

I Have a pod running in a node with an attached pv. My requirement is that I need to use the existing pv, if the pod does down and allocates the pod in another node, for the newly created pod in another node. So what can be done?

Comment: It largely depends how & where k8s is deployed. On few private cloud platforms like `Openstack`, volumes can be attached to multiple VMs. So, even a node goes down, other nodes can still access volume as it's mounted on all nodes. They use some sort of `glusterfs` or `ceph`. On `Azure`, you can attach file shares to pods to persist data.

Comment: Wether this is possible or not depends on what storage system you use. You should update your question with the storage system in use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the persistence volume , then pv stays with pod till its life which means it will persists pod's restarts or deletes. It can only be deleted  by deleting its deployment config.

If your case is to backup the data on pv , then thats different case.

Comment: There are 2 nodes named A and B. Currently, a pod is running in node A and pv is attached to it. If in case the A node goes down and a new pod is allocated to node B, then how could I use the existing pv?

Comment: As you are using the node's local storage as persistence volume , in that case if node goes down  , it will be data loss to your application . You need to come up with backup solution of your data for existing pv as its local to the node and then if the failure occurs , restore that backup to the new pv on other node.

Comment: ok what if I attach the pv to aws ebs with the sample above example.

Comment: thats good , but default setting for ebs is not sufficient , you need to install ebs csi driver & create storage class to make sure that ebs pv sustain throughout the lifecycle of pod.  Use the following to install CSI driver https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html